# Can I use paint stripper in my basement workshop?

Tags: woodworking, staining, wooden-furniture, hardwood-refinishing, custom-cabinetry

I am looking to refinish a pool table that I purchased.  Since it is winter and too cold to do it in my garage, I would like to do it in my basement workshop but I'm worried about the fumes.

I have an air exchanger in the workshop which is designed for a 3000+ sq. ft. home.  I was thinking that I could disconnect the vents from going through the house, then use them to basically filter out the air from the workshop.

Do you think this would be strong enough to keep the room well enough ventilated?

Also, is a respirator necessary with this system?

Please advise, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Paint strippers have different chemical compositions so it is difficult to properly answer your questions.  However, in general,
1. recommend you wait until you can either apply the stripper outside or get proper exhaust ventilation
2. The package on paint strippers will tell you if you should be using a respirator
3. Consider using a non-toxic citrus-based stripper or sanding instead.  (Use a dust mask if sanding)

Comment: Or consider a heat gun.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow the directions on the stripper. When in doubt,  wait for fresh air.  Stripper fumes can be very toxic and some can be flammable. Water based or citrus strippers might be better for indoor use, but still read the label and heed the warnings.

Comment: I have read the instructions.  It recommends to wear a vapor respirator.  However, there are no instructions on there of a ventilation system.  So, I can't make a jugdement.  I just don't know if a 60-100 CFM air exchanger is enough to ventilate a room with the stripper in it.  I don't want everyone in the house to have health problems if I use it because it seaped through the walls.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are too many variables to give a guess, probably the main being how well your house is sealed everywhere.  I think the easiest thing to do is just use a very small amount of the product and see how well/fast it permeates throughout the house.  If you get nothing at use more in increments.